# Importar arquivos txt com pandas

Tags: python, pandas, txt, machine-learning

Estou iniciando na área de machine learning, seguindo um site da internet que sugeriu o modelo inicial a seguir:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataframe = pd.read_fwf('brain_body.txt')
x_values = dataframe[['Brain']]
y_values = dataframe[['Body']]

body_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
body_reg.fit(x_values,y_values)

plt.scatter(x_values,y_values)
plt.plot(x_values,body_reg.predict(x_values))
plt.show()
```

Porém estou tendo o seguinte resultado:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'brain_body.txt'
```

o arquivo txt está na mesma pasta que o arquivo .py principal.

Comment: Uma solução mais fácil é usar o caminho completo do arquivo. O erro pode ocorrer porque o programa executável do python não foi adicionado ao PATH (uma outra solução é adicionar).

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou. Como o arquivo .txt está? Tente utilizar `pd.read_csv` ao invés de `pd.read_fwf` ou o caminho completo do arquivo.

Comment: O arquivo está em linhas e colunas, como se fosse uma tabela

Comment: Estou utilizando através do anaconda, talvez seja uma incompatibilidade

Answer (score 0):

Tente o caminho com ".\":

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataframe = pd.read_fwf('.\\brain_body.txt')
x_values = dataframe[['Brain']]
y_values = dataframe[['Body']]

body_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
body_reg.fit(x_values,y_values)

plt.scatter(x_values,y_values)
plt.plot(x_values,body_reg.predict(x_values))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Não deu certo mano, o erro continuou, mas obrigado pela resposta

Comment: O arquivo está no mesmo diretório do fonte python e de execução do projeto?

Comment: Sim, está. Ambos na mesma pasta